# How to use several css classes to one element?

Tags: html, css

I have a class:

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12, .grid_13, .grid_14, .grid_15, .grid_16 {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Now i say that want to change `display: inline;`->`display: block;` and `float: left;`->`float: none;` foe one element;

I create another class:

```
.logonormal{
float:none;
display:block;
}
```

And i html i say:

```
<header id="banner" role="banner" class="grid_12 logonormal">
```

But i not see `logonormal` in firefox. What im doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without a test case that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `.logonormal` class is defined somewhere *after* the `.grid_12` class in your CSS files. Since the selectors have the same precedence, this is the deciding factor.

Comment: In either case he should see the selector in the inspector – if the CSS file was reloaded properly and the selector really exists.

Comment: @Kolink: im sure that `.logonormal` defined after `.grid_12` becouse css file which contain class `.grid_12` append early that file contains class `.logonormal`.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed Kolink's suggestion already (the order of the css selectors), then perhaps you can increase the [specificity of your css declaration](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Something like this maybe?

```
 header.logonormal {
      float:none;
      display:block;
 }
```

Good luck.